# How to eager load Aggregates in Laravel with Eloquent?

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

in my application I have a long list of Categories. I load them with this:

```php
$categories = Categories::all();
```

In the `Categories` there is this function:

```php
public function transactions()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Transactions::class);
}

public function getPreviousActivityAttribute() {
    return $this->transactions()
        ->where('date', '<' Carbon::now()->firstOfMonth())
        ->sum('amount');
}
```

I render this list of Categories as a table. Each row is calling `$category->previousActivity`.

This results in n+1 database queries, where n is the number of Categories (and its a lot). Apart from `previousActiviy` I display other Aggregates aswell (some do `SUM` others do `AVG`, etc.).

By the way. There are a lot of transactions. I cannot load them all using `Categories::with('transactions')->get()`. This would require too much memory.

Is there a way to eager load aggregates? There is a `withCount` method on the query builder, but it does not really help here.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: ```$categories = Categories::with('transactions')->get();``` doesn't work ? Or did I misunderstand what you wanted ?

Comment: @Takachi Too many transactions. I cannot load thousands of them into memory.

Comment: I think you can do something like ```$categories = Categories::leftJoin('transactions', 'transactions.category_id', 'category.id')->get()``` but you will not get any relationship...

Comment: Have you added `previousActivity` to the model's `$appends`?

Answer (score 1):

Attach a function to the `withCount` attribute in the model˚s constructor like this to always eager load this count.

```
public function __construct(array $attributes = array())
{
    parent::__construct($attributes);

    $this->withCount['transactions as total'] = function ($query) {
        $query->select(DB::raw(
            'SUM(IFNULL(amount, 0)) as relationsum'
        ));
    };
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A clean solution would be to use `withCount` as follows:

In Categories.php:

```
public function withPreviousActivity()
    {
        return $this->withCount([
            'transactions as previous_activity' => function ($query) {
                $query->select(DB::raw("SUM(IFNULL(amount,0)) as transactions_count"))->where('date', '<', Carbon::now()->firstOfMonth());
            },
        ]);
    }
```

Somewhere else:

```
dump(Categories::withPreviousActivity()->get()->toArray());
```